# Issue with changing css with Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

[image]

I am trying to make 2 step checkout modal

My first step modal is inside div with id ="step1" and with style display block

and step2 with id="step2" with style display none

My buttons inside my modal footer:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="check_address();" id="next_button">Next >></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="back_address();" id="back_button" style="display:none;">Back <<</button>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="checkout_button" style="display:none;">Check Out >></button>
```

Inside my cart.php file I have an function check_address that corresponds to parser file and ajax that looks like this:

```
function check_address() {
    var data = {
        'full_name': jQuery('#full_name').val(),
        'email': jQuery('#email').val(),
        'street': jQuery('#street').val(),
        'street2': jQuery('#street2').val(),
        'city': jQuery('#city').val(),
        'state': jQuery('#state').val(),
        'zip_code': jQuery('#zip_code').val(),
        'country': jQuery('#country').val(),

    };
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/E-Shop/admin/parsers/check_address.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) { //this data is what is forwarded back from the parser file
            if (data != 'passed') {
                jQuery('#payment-errors').html(data);
            }
            if (data == 'passed') {
                jQuery('#payment-errors').html("");
                jQuery('#step1').css("display", "none");
                jQuery('#step2').css("display", "block");
                jQuery('#next_button').css("display", "none");
                jQuery('#back_button').css("display", "inline-block");
                jQuery('#checkout_button').css("display", "inline-block");

            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("An error occured!");
        },
    });
}
```

After I submit my first step form, I get output from check_adress.php parser : "passed"  from my last line in check_address.php

```
if(!empty($greske)){
    echo display_greske($greske);
}else{
    echo 'passed';
}
```

my check_address.php script:  https://pastebin.com/1qA5Tx08

but the jQuery doesn't show or change my css display attributes

Comment: Why don't you use `.hide()` and `.show()`?

Comment: Are you seeing anything in `#payment-errors`?

Comment: I think there is nothing being outputted from payment errors

Comment: If I put my display changes inside data != "passed" I am able to see step 2 modal, but than my validations doesn't run

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: console log data returns my validations that are required

Comment: Then it's not returning `passed`, so why should it go to step 2?

Comment: I am sorry, It does return passed I didn't filled out my fields

Comment: Try `data = data.trim();`. I'll bet there's some extra whitespace.

Comment: Desn't fix it, I have used this modals from bootstrap custom componenets , but my main framework is foundation, maybe that is the problem. But I don't see why would it be if I can change it under != 'passed'

Comment: If you examine the elements in the console, do you see the changes to the CSS?

Comment: I don't see any changes, but Response payload in dev tools returns 1: empty and under that 2: passed, preview returns just passed, as you can see in the picture above

Comment: So it's showing `passed` in the `#payment-errors` field? Earlier you said "there is nothing being outputted from payment errors".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `1:` and `2:` in the response payload. Are you returning JSON?

Comment: The only thing that should be in response payload is "passed". If anything else is there, it won't match.

Comment: It returns data if its not equal to passed, yes I am returning json array from parser file , where I am checking if its required

Comment: So which is it returning, the error data or passed? It sounds like it's returning both.

Comment: console log only returns "passed" forwarded back from the parser file

Comment: Then it must be executing those statements. If you set a breakpoint, does it stop there?

Comment: I don't know how to use breakpoints, this is my parser file : https://pastebin.com/1qA5Tx08 , you can see the response "passed" and my params are returning inputted form data

Comment: You need to use the Javacript debugger in the browser. [Javascript debugging for beginners](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) or [Javscript Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: My function that displays errors: https://pastebin.com/STUUAwCu, but I don't see why it would work on if data != 'passed' and not equal passed, I am looking into it right now.

Comment: You have a blank line before the `<?php` at the beginning of the script, so the output has a newline before `passed`.

Comment: `data = data.trim()` should have removed that, though.

Comment: I am not sure where do you see that mistake ? I have tried including data trim inside the ajax function

Comment: In https://pastebin.com/1qA5Tx08 `<?php` is on line 2, it should be on line 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the blank line before `<?php` at the beginning of the `check_address.php` script.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url :url,
    type : 'post',
    data : data,
    success : function (data) {
    //    location.reload(); 
        if (data != 'passed') {
            jQuery('#payment_errors').html(data);
        }
        if (data == 'passed') {
            // alert('passed');
            //clear errors
            jQuery('#payment_errors').html("");
            jQuery('#step1').css("display","none");
            jQuery('#step2').css("display","block");
            jQuery('#next_button').css("display","none");
            jQuery('#back_button').css("display","inline-block");
            jQuery('#check_out_button').css("display","inline-block");
        }

    },
    error : function () {
        alert("Something wrong with the child options.");
    }
});
```

Comment: you need to change echo alert in check~_address.php to small letter 'passed'